# Django: Difficulty understanding how to access field values in templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

The following code is giving me an output I don't expect. Help to interpret my code would be appreciated (I'm very new to Django).

I've created this model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
  question = models.TextField()
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
def __str__(self):
    return self.question
```

With a corresponding view:

```
def home(request):
questions = Question.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
return render(request, 'core/home.html', {'questions':questions})
```

That is called by an HTML template:

```
<div id = "centreBlock" >
                {{ questions }}
                {{questions.created_date}}
        </div>
        <div id = "rightBlock">
            <h2> Other questions</h2>
            {% for quest in questions %}
                <h3><a href="">{{ quest.created_date }}</a></h3>
                <p>{{ quest.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

The second line of Django code `{{ questions.created_date}}` in the template doesn't give anything (all the other code works as I expect). Why is this? I was expecting to see a list of the Created Dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `questions` is a QuerySet and has no attribute `created_date`.
If you want to display all dates from a QuerySet then you'd have to get it explicitly or loop over and show each questions `created_date`

```
{% for question in questions %}
    {{ question.created_date }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: OK thanks. Is there anyway of passing an object directly to the template or do I have to use a QuerySet?

Comment: Yes, there is and you've been doing it currently by passing `questions` in your template context dict. `return render(request, 'core/home.html', {'questions':questions, 'add_another_object': tuple()})`, will for example make a tuple object available under the variable `add_another_object`.

Comment: How should I pass a dict and access it in the template. None of the code I've tried works.

Comment: You pass it like above, and access it like a normal dict within your template.

Answer (score 0):

The template variable `questions` is a queryset of questions. You can't access individual fields from the queryset, you have to loop through it.

```
{% for question in questions %}
{{ question.created_date }} 
{% endfor %}
```